# JAVA While loop - last else if statement not working

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What is the password?");
        Scanner new2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int input = 0;

        while(input <= 5 )
        {
            String password = new2.nextLine();
            if(!password.equals("bluesky123")){
                System.out.println("Incorrect password");
                input++;
            }

            else if("bluesky123".equals(password)) {
                System.out.println("You got it right!");
                break;
            }
            else if(input == 5) {
                System.out.println("maximum number of attempts reached");
                break;
            }
        }    
    }

}
```

basically, once I hit the 5 loops, it just says "incorrect password" and breaks. not the "maximum attempts" message.

Comment: How do you now it doesn't start over? it loops right back and waits for another password to be entered. Enter wrong password 5 times, and *then* the program will terminate. Did you perhaps intend for the `println("What is the password?")` to be *inside* the loop?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized I asked the wrong question. Basically whenever I hit the 5th attempt, it still only outputs the "incorrect password" but breaks.

Comment: Your logic is also suspect. If I'm reading it right, you'll never enter the code block for `input == 5`. You cover all cases with the first 2 blocks, and with either exit on the next loop where `input` is 5 or more (enter `!password.equals` raises the variable to 5), or break because you got the right password.

Comment: It doesn't "break". The loop *ends*, because the loop condition (`input <= 5`) is false. Your code doesn't work because if `!password.equals("bluesky123")` is false and first `if` statement skips, then `"bluesky123".equals(password)` is definitely true, so there is *no way* for second `if` statement to skip, ergo there is no path thru the code that you ever allow `else if(input == 5)` to execute.

Comment: Suggestion: move the verification of `input == 5` to the first case, and have the String verifications come after.

Comment: How about showing us exactly the output you do get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(input <= 5 )
    {
        String password = new2.nextLine();
        if(!password.equals("bluesky123")){
            System.out.println("Incorrect password");
            input++;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("You got it right!");
            break;
        }

        if((input == 5) && (!password.equals("bluesky123"))) {
            System.out.println("maximum number of attempts reached");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Your logic has some flaws. You have to pay attention to how JAVA processes if / else if

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/if_else_statement_in_java.htm

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to annotate:

This if statement will always be evaluated:

```
        if(!password.equals("bluesky123")){
            System.out.println("Incorrect password");
            input++;
        }
```

This if statement will only be evaluated if the password is "bluesky123".  In this case, it will always evaluate to `true`.

```
        else if("bluesky123".equals(password)) {
            System.out.println("You got it right!");
            break;
        }
```

There is no case when this if statement will ever be evaluated.  Once if-else finds a statement that is true, it will skip all others in that section.

```
        else if(input == 5) {
            System.out.println("maximum number of attempts reached");
            break;
        }
```

In your case, you should consider a nested if (i.e. an if inside another if).

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code it is working! The only thing that you need to do is to move the follow line to inside the while loop

```
 System.out.println("What is the password?");
```

Doing this it will print "Incorrect password" and then it will print again 
"What is the password?"

Because in the way that it is working now seems that the software is not waiting the password to be retyped when in fact it is.

Comment: This answer unfortunately no longer applies, because OP changed the question.